# Can I use Plotly's Custom Buttons to update `shared_yaxes` in a faceted plot?

Tags: javascript, python, r, plotly

I am using plotly and I have a figure with subplots. I'd like to include in it a button to toggle the property `shared_yaxes`. Is this possible?

Here a reproducible example (in python). Consider the [official simple subplot example](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/):

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]), row=1, col=2)
```

This produces: 
[image]

Now, you can simply use the `shared_yaxes` argument of `make_subplots` to force the same y-scale on both plots.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, shared_yaxes=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]), row=1, col=2)
```

And then you get:

[image]

Now I want to include a custom control (ideally a checkbox) to toggle that property (I've done this using R and Shiny, but now I want this plotly-based solution).

I've tried with [custom buttons](https://plot.ly/python/custom-buttons/#methods), for example using this code below, but I cannot make it work.

```
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[
    go.layout.Updatemenu(type="buttons",
                         direction="left",
                         buttons=list([
                             dict(args=[{
                                 "shared_yaxes": True
                             }],
                                  label="Shared axes",
                                  method="relayout"),
                             dict(args=[{
                                 "shared_yaxes": False
                             }],
                                  label="Independent axes",
                                  method="relayout")
                         ]),
                         xanchor="left",
                         yanchor="top"),
])
```

[image]

Any ideas how to make it work would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by switching between `'matches': 'y'` and `'matches': None` for `'yaxis2'` in the setup below:

**Output 1:**

[image]

**Output 2:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
# imports
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# plotly basic setup
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, shared_yaxes=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]), row=1, col=2)

# plotly figure updates
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        go.layout.Updatemenu(buttons=list([
            dict(label='Shared',
                 method='relayout',
                 args=['yaxis2', {'anchor': 'x2', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0],
                                  'matches': 'y', 'showticklabels': False}]),
            dict(label='Not shared',
                 method='relayout',
                 args=['yaxis2', {'anchor': 'x2', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0],
                                  'matches': None, 'showticklabels': True}]),
        ]),
        )
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

---

**Edit:** Here's a setup that should match your button preferences:

[image]

**Code:**

```
# imports
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# plotly basic setup
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, shared_yaxes=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]), row=1, col=2)

# plotly figure updates
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        go.layout.Updatemenu(type='buttons',
                             direction='left',
                             xanchor='left',
                             yanchor='top',
                             buttons=list([
                                    dict(label='Shared axes',
                                         method='relayout',
                                         args=['yaxis2', {'anchor': 'x2', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0],
                                                          'matches': 'y', 'showticklabels': False}]),
                                    dict(label='Independent axes',
                                         method='relayout',
                                         args=['yaxis2', {'anchor': 'x2', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0],
                                                          'matches': None, 'showticklabels': True}]),
                                            ]),
        )
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: cool, many thanks. My use case is actually more complex, 'cause I am generating several subplots dynamically and there are multiple rows and columns. But this should get me started. I was hoping to be able to trigger the very same routine that runs when you have set `shared_yaxes=True`, and not updating each subplot like here. But I guess this is the way to do it. Many thanks again.

Comment: @elikesprogramming Ah, I see... This was the best I could do at the moment. Please share if you find a more efficient way!