# Custom zoom buttons in Plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I am plotting the information of a genome, which contains the information of 24 chromosomes. They are all plotted on the same graph as shown on the graph bellow.

Now, what I want to do is to add a dropdown buttom with 25 unique options in order to view the graph with all the information (default scenario) or plotting only the information of a given chromosome, that is to say, to zoom in to a given range.

I have seen several options to add buttons to a graph but I have not seen in the documentation if:

1. It is possible to add a dropdown button, As it will be handier to deal with 24 buttons within this format
2. It is possible to add a button with the functionality to zoom in and out within a given range

[image]

Any guesses about these two doubts?

Comment: I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58593825/can-i-use-plotlys-custom-buttons-to-update-shared-yaxes-in-a-faceted-plot) to be very helpful